# Can WebStorm automatically complete global style names in string templates?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, css-modules

When using CSS Modules, it is often the case to write a combination style. The unfortunate thing is that the global class name in the string template has no code hints.

As the picture shows:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

## I want the letter "s" in the second picture to appear the same code hint as in the first picture

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

[image]

what does your CSS module look like? Please share your global class definition

Comment: I mean, I want the letter "s" in the second picture to appear the same code hint as in the first picture...